# When running tests through CucumberWithSerenity, Steps from the module other than where TestRunner is located are ignored

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Project structure:

```
    parent_module
                 |_api
                 |    |_src
                 |         |_test
                 |               |_java
                 |               |     |_behavior
                 |               |     |         |_step -> ApiSteps.class
                 |               |     |
                 |               |     |_runner
                 |               |             |_TestRunner.class
                 |               |
                 |               |_resources -> features
                 |
                 |_common
                 |        |_src
                 |            |_main
                 |                  |_java
                 |                         |_name.package
                 |                                      |_step
                 |                                             |_BaseStep.class
                 |
                 |_web
                      |_...
```

TestRunner.class:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"name.package.behavior.step", "behavior.step"})
public class TestRunner {...}
```

When running tests (first mvn install for common, then mvn verify for api), the steps from common are ignored. The Serenity report is highlighted as Pending.

A class with steps is not found.

How can I solve this problem? Maybe someone came across a similar, thank you in advance.